# Vue 3 safe to use for new big projects?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vuejs3

I will be developing an application for a big company and im wondering if it is safe to use Vue 3 in its current state. Support for global state, routing and unit testing is a must but im not sure if it is supported in a stable manner. The next version of Vue Test Utils supports Vue 3 but is currently in beta. As a fan of Test Driven Development the latter is an absolute must.

Should I stick with Vue 2? Use Vue 3 and progressively enhance?

I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;**
It totally depends on how you are willing to move forward.

Vue.js 2.x is quite stable now with all the required problems and solutions. In my personal experience working on 2.x is smoother for me until now. There is no such blocking obstacle I have found either developing a single module or a whole multi-page application. You probably get all your problems resolved here at SO only.

Vue.js 3.x recently shipped officially, and I have yet to try on it but just by seeing the overall documentation, I can fairly say that they shipped many new refactors and features. One of them is *composition API* which I am currently looking over. Developing a project using vue.js 3 will not impact much differently as compared to vue.js 2 because they mostly stay with similar component structuring and so you can feel behaviors to be the same. However, if you are willing to use new features then yes it will be really good, but then probably you will start the problem threads related to vue.js 3 if one occurs during your development which probably can cause a block to parallel development.

IMHO - I would have started with 2.x because I am quite handy on it and probably my other teammates are also quite familiar with it so that can be a reason. Also until now as per official docs migration build for migrating from existing 2.X to 3.x is yet to be done and it can ship out soon. So try out 3.x on any small project and then you can simply migrate

Comment: I think the biggest blocker is Vue Test Utils. Version 2 for Vue 3 is still in beta and im one of those guys that write tests before code :(

Comment: My Team is familiar with Vue 2 but I really see the benefits of using the composition API.